# new window with same content and a small change

Tags: window

I have a page in php which has several check boxes. whenever a user selects one of the check boxes, I want to change the check box with an undo button. can you please give me a clue how I should do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you could have an undo link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="undo">undo</a>

$(document).ready(){ function(){    //wait until the page has loaded
  $(".undo").click(function(){      //bind to the click event of your undo link
    $(".checkbox").attr('checked', !$(".checkbox").attr('checked'))  // Toggle the checkbox
   })
})
```

Of course, this assumes you only have one checkbox. Would need to know more about your current set up to understand how you want the user experience to go.